# How to remove dot and space from beginning of filenames

Tags: shell, regular-expression, rename

I'm trying to change jpg files named with a dot and a space at the beginning and with a missing dot before the end (like this `. Startjpg` to `Start.jpg`

The dot makes the files hidden from `sed` and `ls -al` lists those files so I'm piping `ls -al` to `sed`. I've read through many manuals online and I always get this error

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 6: unknown command: `/'
```

I've tried

```
ls -al | sed -r '/^\./*.*/g'
ls -al | sed -r '/^\.//g'
ls -al | sed -r '/.*/[\.]g'
ls -al | sed 's/^\./\\1*./g'
```

and many more and even many more many more.

also I need to change filejpg to file.jpg

Comment: I've spent **4 hours** for this :/ it might take just **a minute** for you

Comment: You say you are *also* trying to change `filejpg` to `file.jpg`.  What are you trying to do in the first place?

Comment: @drs I'm trying to rename bunch of `. filejpg` files to `file.jpg`

Comment: There is a `rename` or `prename` command (part of Perl) which is a *much* better tool for this job. Note that there is a non-perl rename tool also sometimes called `rename`, it's much less powerful.

Comment: @user251046, give us the exact input and the exact output. Also let us know what you are trying to do by editing your question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With the Perl `rename` tool (which is called `rename` on Debian and friends including Ubuntu, it may be `prename` elsewhere):

```bash
rename -n 's/(?<!\.)jpg$/.jpg/' *  # -n makes it show you what it'll do,
                                   # but not actually do it. Remove the -n to
                                   # actually rename
```

To break down that patter: the `jpg$` means "ends with 'jpg'". The `(?<!\.)` means 'there isn't a dot before that 'jpg'". That prevents you from changing `foo.jpg` into `foo..jpg`, which would be silly.

The `*` is the normal shell wildcard; `rename` takes a list of files to consider renaming. You can of course do `/path/to/dir/*`, pass a list of file names, use in conjunction with `find`, etc.

Removing dots and spaces from the beginning is fairly easy too:

```bash
rename -n 's/^[. ]+//' *          # trying -n first is good practice
```

That will remove all dots and spaces at the beginning. It'll turn `.  .  . foo` into `foo`.

Normally, `*` shell expansion won't yield files that have a name starting with a dot (hidden files). One option is to use `.*`; that'll also yield the two special entries `.` (current directory) and `..` (parent directory). That should be harmless in this case; the first command will ignore them (they don't end in `jpg`); the second command will try to rename them, but that should just produce an error. An alternative is find:

```
find -type f -exec rename -n 's/^[. ]+//' '{}' +
```

`-type f` will limit to only files. You can of course also use any of find's other options as well.

Comment: The `-n` option doesn't list anything and without it it unfortunately doesn't rename anything.I guess that's because the files are hidden to it.

Comment: @user251046 try it with `.*` instead of `*`. That'll wind up passing it the special entries `.` and `..` as well, but it should ignore those.

Comment: How did you learn all this? You're amazing! Maybe you can show me where you found this out? Also I have now one file named IMG_32347 how to add .jpg to it?

Comment: @user251046 if its one file, by far the easiest way is `mv IMG_32347 IMG_32347.jpg`. I learned all of this from using Linux for over 15 years now, and Perl for even longer.

Comment: Thank You for your reply, I know I can just do mv but I'm asking because this is useful to know. This is what I've just tried (and failed) `rename -n 's/(?<!\.flac)/.flac\$/' *`

Comment: @user251046 I just solved it with this `rename -f 's/(?<!\.flac)$/.flac/' *` :D

Comment: prename and rename is installed in ubuntu by default so it seems thay are different

Comment: @user251046 if its like on Debian, they're `rename` is provided by the alternatives system, but all the alternatives work close enough to the Perl rename. There are actually two different perl renames, one is an extended version of the other. RedHat has (or at least had) a completely different, non-Perl, rename command as `rename`.

Comment: @deroberto what is "alternatives system"

Comment: @user251046 See the `update-alternatives` manpage or ask a new question about it.

Comment: @derobert What you saw on Red Hat is the `rename` command from `util-linux`. Debian and derivatives are the non-standard ones, shipping as they are an incompatible command under the name `rename`. In their defense, the Perl rename is useful, unlike the util-linux one which is never what you actually want.

Answer (score 4):

While `sed` is a very useful and versatile tool, you're not using it properly.  It's best used to match and substitute strings in text files; it can't directly rename files on the filesystem.

This task is better suited for a bash one-liner (assuming that's your shell).  To rename something like `. filejpg` to `file.jpg`, use this:

```
find . -name '. *' -print0 | while read -d $'\0' file; do short_file=${file%jpg}.jpg; mv "$file" "${short_file:4}"; done
```

---

**Explanation**

`find` is a program that returns paths to files that match a certain file property, in this case the file's name.  If all you wanted to know was what .jpg files are in subdirectories of your current path, you would do `find . -name "*.jpg"`.  Normally this outputs each file on a new line.  The `-print0` makes it separate the matches with a null character instead.  This allows for proper handling of filenames with spaces when we pass the output to the next commands.

The `|` character is known as a pipe.  It tells the shell to take the output of the command on the left and pass it as the input to the command on the right, in this case, the `read` command within the `while` loop.

The `read` command is used to take the output of `find` and assign it to a variable, `file`.  Normally this would assign values to `file` each word at a time, but the `-d $'\0'$` causes the assignments to be delimited by the null character (matching how we delimited the files in `find` by using the `-print0` flag).

The while loops causes `read` to iteratively assign values to "file" for each matching filename.  The `do` and `done` are part of the standard bash syntax for a while loop:

```
while <something is true>; do
    <run some commands>
done
```

In this case, our "run some command" first fixes the extension of the file name and assigns it to a new variable: `short_file=${file%jpg}.jpg` changes `. filejpg` to `. file.jpg`.  Then it runs `mv` to rename the file, removing the `.` at the beginning of the extension-corrected filename: `mv "$file" ${short_file:2}`.

Comment: how to rename then?

Comment: can you explain please how this "one-liner" works?

Comment: vote up requires 15 reputation

Comment: Thanks for your thorough explanation.I don't understand this part though `*Normally this would assign values to file each word at a time, but the -d $'\0'$ causes the assignments to be delimited by the null character (matching how we delimited the files in find by using the -print0 flag).*`It works, how to select this as my accepted answer **too?**

Comment: you can only select one answer to each question.  derobert's answer is a little cleaner so it's probably better to leave it as the selected one.

Comment: If you use the default delimeter, then `read` (or other tools along the one-liner pipeline) could misinterpret file names with spaces or new lines in them (thinking that they are two separate files). The `NUL` character (along with `/`) are not permitted in Linux file names so by using it as the delimeter, you *ensure* that your tools are handling every file name correctly.

Comment: For an example of when the default delimeter fails, try `for file in $(find . -name "*jpg"); do echo $file; done`.  Make sure you're in a directory that contains a file ending in `jpg` with a space in its name (you can quickly create one with `touch 'one file.jpg'`).

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the other answers, you can use the graphical tool [GPRename](http://gprename.sourceforge.net/). It can replace characters, truncate filenames, etc. The advantage is that there's a built-in preview function to check the new filenames before renaming them. But since it works on one directory at a time, it will be inconvenient to use it with numerous folders in sub-folders. But for less than 10 folders it's not a problem.